# MariaDB NoSQL data using dynamic columns or JSON

Tags: json, nosql, mariadb, dynamic-columns

I want to store dynamic statistical data in a NoSQL way - a structured document and be able to work on a parameter basis.

e.g.

```json
{
  'client': 1245,
  'amount': 25425,
  'create_date': '2019-01-01'
}
```

As I understand, MariaDB has two different approaches since version 10.2:

- using BLOB column data type and dynamic column functions COLUMN_CREATE, COLUMN_GET, COLUMN_LIST, ...
- using VARCHAR column and JSON specific functions  JSON_EXISTS, JSON_QUERY, ...

I see some pros and cons in both ways:

- **Dynamic columns**

  - pros

    - seems faster
  - cons

    - less universal
    - less standard
    - suited more for one depth of parameters
- **JSON**

  - pros

    - better in complex structure
    - more standard when exporting
    - easier data creation
  - cons

    - seems slower and less robust

I also feel the development of the JSON approach is more active in recent years.

Since I need to decide which way to go for the next couple of years and I haven't found any comparison of the approaches can someone shed some light on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no comments on my topic, so I can at least say what we decided for and why.

**We went the way of JSON because of these reasons:**

- we do not operate large scale data (max 100,000 records), so the speed is not quite an issue here (I did not have to make benchmarks)
- there is definitely easier export of data and than easier analysis with available tools
- there are more ways to alter structural data in JSON format
- there is better readability of data using visual database tools
- there is easier data serialization between app and data layer
- finally, my personal feeling there is more active development on JSON side

Comment: Good points, I wish the MariaDb folks would just capitulate already and support MySQL's JSON standard.. In the meantime there is the 'mysql_json' compatibility plugin if you need to do MySQL->MariaDb replication.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering this same question! There isn't much information I can find on which data storage method to use for these use cases. Hopefully someone with some MariaDB expertise can enlighten us